# Get url parameters from within a widget - wirecloud

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I'm thinking in developing a mashup in wirecloud to support the frontend of my app, but I have some doubts. I hope you can solve me:
- Can I develop a widget which get parameters from the url? I mean, I need to get some parameters which come from an external web form, in the url... So when I call the mashup wirecloud url, is there anyway to get the url parameters from within a widget?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Currently WireCloud doesn't support this, you can create a feature request on the WireCloud [issue tracker](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues) as this seems to be usefull.